# Flip numbers in tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, binary, reverse, flip

I have a list of tuples sorted by the keys which are binary numbers as string types.

This is how it looks now

```
('000', 'Jo')
('001', 'Ja')
('010', 'Ji')
('011', 'Je')
('100', 'Ju')
('101', 'Jy')
('110', 'Jl')
('111', 'Jk')
```

But now I want the characters in the strings to look like

```
(000, 'jo')
(100, 'ja')
(010, 'ji')
(110, 'je')
(001, 'ju')
(101, 'jy')
(011, 'jl')
(111, 'jk')
```

But to still be with the same value.

So, how do I flip the first element in the tuple to get the output?

Comment: what is the etc. can you give the whole desired output?

Comment: In your question you mentioned you made a `dict` but you are showing us something like a `list` of `tuples` (not really a list, either). May you kindly show the original `dict` and the whole desired output? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keys aren't binary numbers, they're strings *representing* binary numbers. To reverse a string, you can use `slice` notation:

```
s = s[::-1]
```

To reverse all of the (`str`) keys in a dictionary:

```
dct = {k[::-1]: v for k, v in dct.items()}
```

To simultaneously calculate the numerical values using the `int(s, 2)` notation:

```
dct = {int(k[::-1], 2): v for k, v in dct.items()}
```

Comment: i dont think this yields he desired output that the OP wants.

Comment: ah, he wants to reverse the string... i'll edit the question to make it clearer... lolz...

Comment: can i in the same time convert the binary strings to int? i know about the int(b, 2), but how would i do it for all at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

if the keys are binary numbers instead of strings as in the original question - thus something like

```
mydict = {
    0b1100111: 'Jo'
}
```

then they can be reversed in this way:

```
dct = {'{0:b}'.format(k)[::-1]: v for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

but the new keys will be strings (this to let you observe the reversed bits). If you want them to remain numbers, you can convert them back to integers:

```
dct = {int('{0:b}'.format(k)[::-1], 2): v for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

(supposing you are using python 2.6+)

Comment: why would `b` appear in a binary number?

Comment: since this is the python syntax for binary numbers (http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-bininteger), to distinguish them from integers: `0b1100111 == 103`